# dnsmasq pool without assigned ip

Tags: dnsmasq

I have a simple dnsmasq v2.80 in an embedded device which I want to use as DHCP server for autoprovisioning purposes.

I want two pools (one static and one dynamic)

What I have is this one:

```
#
# main dnsmasq config file
#

user=nobody
group=nogroup

log-dhcp
dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-rapid-commit
no-dhcp-interface=lo
dhcp-name-match=set:wpad-ignore,wpad
dhcp-ignore-names=tag:wpad-ignore
dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases

dhcp-option=tag:v69_static_pool_1,option:dns-server,1.2.3.254
dhcp-option=tag:v69_static_pool_1,option:router,1.2.3.253
dhcp-option=tag:v69_static_pool_1,option:ntp-server,1.2.3.252

dhcp-range=set:v69_dynamic_pool_1,10.250.0.2,10.250.0.254,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-option=tag:v69_dynamic_pool_1,option:dns-server,10.250.0.1
dhcp-option=tag:v69_dynamic_pool_1,option:router,10.250.0.1
dhcp-option=tag:v69_dynamic_pool_1,option:ntp-server,10.250.0.1

dhcp-range=1.2.3.1,1.2.3.254,255.255.255.0,infinite
dhcp-host=dc:2c:6e:ef:09:33,1.2.3.2,set:v69_static_pool_1
```

and the network interface

```
   link/ether ba:86:04:04:64:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 10.250.0.1/24 scope global v69
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet 1.2.3.1/24 scope global v69
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 fe80::b886:4ff:fe04:6444/64 scope link 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But what I want is to don't waste ip addresses because I will be using public IP addresses to assign to cpes in a network. I'm used to work with mikrotik routers and while the interface has a static ip address is enought to allow me to assign IP's out of the interface range.

And also I want to assure that the static pool is not used to assign to dynamic hosts.

Is it possible with dnsmasq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And also I want to assure that the static pool is not used to assign to dynamic hosts.

If you don't want to hand out dynamic addresses from a DHCP range, using the `static` keyword, described [in the documentation](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html):

> The optional `<mode>` keyword may be `static` which tells dnsmasq to enable DHCP
> for the network specified, but not to dynamically allocate IP addresses: only
> hosts which have static addresses given via --dhcp-host or from /etc/ethers
> will be served.

That would look something like this:

```
dhcp-option=tag:v69_static_pool_1,option:dns-server,1.2.3.254
dhcp-option=tag:v69_static_pool_1,option:router,1.2.3.253
dhcp-option=tag:v69_static_pool_1,option:ntp-server,1.2.3.252

dhcp-range=set:v69_static_pool_1,1.2.3.1,static,255.255.255.0,infinite
dhcp-host=dc:2c:6e:ef:09:33,1.2.3.2
```

Comment: Yup, i've tried it, but what i want is some way to don't use the 1.2.3.1/24 ip address in my network interface because I don't want to waste public ip addresses beucause i need 1 for the router (the gateway) and one for the dhcp box.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. You don't need to use the `1.2.3.1/24` address anywhere. Your DHCP box needs an address on that network, but it sounds like you already expect that. That's the only real requirement.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, this is exactly what i'm asking. If it is possible to lease an ip address with dnsmasq which my dhcp box does not have any in the specific network, in this case would be to declare the dhcp-range 1.2.3.0/24 as static in the dnsmasq config BUT i don't want (if it is possible) to assign an ip from that network to my dhcp box.

Comment: That is not possible. Your DHCP box requires an address on the network for which you are distributing addresses.

Comment: Yup, thanks you very much, i've figured it out reading other articles.